# How does a non-admin Windows 7 user associate file types with GNU Emacs?

Tags: windows-7, emacs

I have GNU Emacs 23.4 installed (or, rather, unzipped) into `C:\Program Files (x86)\emacs-23.4` on my Win7 64-bit system.

It works fine except that when logged in as a non-administrative user I cannot associate files with the GNU Emacs executeables (I've tried to associate a given file type with `runemacs.exe` and with `emacsclientw.exe`).  I can browse to the file in the associate dialog, but when I hit "open" it's just ignored.

It works totally fine when I'm logged in as an admin user.  (And it worked fine in XP.)

I have found the following: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/in-windows-7-how-do-i-change-the-open-with/c4a2ad7e-125c-4526-be20-c8f24f18fbfc but I'd prefer to not have to fiddle with registry entries if there's another way to accomplish this.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you right-click on a file you want to associate and select "Open With...", is there no checkbox for "Always use the selected program to open this kind of file"?

Comment: The checkbox is there and I can select it.  But when I browse to `runemacs.exe` or `emacsclientw.exe` and then hit "Open" on the association dialog my choice is totally ignored.  The GNU Emacs icon does *not* then appear in the "Other programs" section of the dialog and the association does not get made.  (It all works perfectly fine when I'm logged in as an admin user.)

Comment: What if you try to associate with `emacs.exe`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had the same problem and I've found that the registry entry has to be

```
emacs-path\bin\emacsclientw -n "%1"
```

After many attempts to make the GNU Emacs Windows build work to my satisfaction, I always come back to the [patched EmacsW32 build](http://ourcomments.org/Emacs/EmacsW32.html).  Among other things, it provides an installer that adds file associations and other shell extensions.  I've found that it always handles the "Open With" problem correctly.  Unfortunately, the latest patched build is of Emacs 23.1.

Answer (score 2):

If you had a previous version of emacs installed then windows will have associated the name emacsclientw.exe and runemacs.exe with the older version path. To successfully use a new version of emacs you have to remove those associations from the registry with regedit.exe.

Remove the entries:

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\emacsclientw.exe

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\runemacs.exe

Please also see
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/how-do-i-remove-programs-from-the-other-programs/73a34fc6-b968-429f-9e5e-a0873d67eed9?msgId=1946ffef-cf76-49c6-adb8-0850e1c8610d

Answer (score 0):

Same problem trying to associate Allegro Free Physical Viewer rev 16.6 to .brd files.

It turns out that the registry key had the wrong path to the application.  I ran regedit navigated to:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT > Applications > allegro_free_viewer > shell > open > command
```

copied out the path and tried that in a CMD window and got path not found (bad path).

I navigated a explore window to the path of the application and copied that path into the registry "command" value, closed regedit, and it worked.